# Loadrunner Error -35055: Invalid regular expression

Tags: regex, loadrunner, vugen

I have a simple string and I need to values of masterId and datasetId...
masterId=27972&datasetId=4968&from

I tried below to get those values but I am getting invalid regular expression error

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=Correlation1",
    "RegExp=masterId\=(.+?)&datasetId\=(.+?)&from",
    "Ordinal=All",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    LAST);
```

I have tried this regular expression in Jmeter and regex tester, it works. Can anyone help me to point what am I doing wrong in loadrunner?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might not want to escape `=`, and this might simply work:

```
masterId=(.+?)&datasetId=(.+?)&from
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cWWPqM/1/)

#### Reference

[LoadRunner Correlation with web_reg_save_param_regexp](https://www.jds.net.au/correlation-with-regex/)

Comment: I have tried that too. I know its a simple regular expression but in Vugen its not working at all.

Comment: Could you post the complete error description? Have you tried to point to the URL under Search filters?

SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "RequestUrl=*/myurl/index.html",

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too but still giving the same error. Below is the detailed error - 
Action.c(47): Continuing after Error -35055: Invalid regular expression   [MsgId: MERR-35055]
Action.c(47): Registering web_reg_save_param_regexp highest severity level was "ERROR"   [MsgId: MMSG-26389]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(.+?)` to `(.*?)`.

No need to put `\` in your RegExp but avoid using `(.*?)` in regular expression. Please use following instead:

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=Correlation1",
    "RegExp=masterId=([0-9]+)&datasetId=([0-9]+)&from",
    "Ordinal=All",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    LAST);
```